# Google BigQuery and Google API Client Package

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am a DevOps engineer at a fintech startup and we are trying to send data from GCS to BigQuery in Airflow, but are getting the following error message in the logs with reference to:

> /site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py, line ___, in _retry_request for retry_num in range(num_retries + 1):
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Are there any parameters that need to be adjusted to get this task to work?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to run [this example](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/contrib/example_dags/example_gcs_to_bq_operator.html)? Also, did configuring the Number of Retries solved the issue for you?

Answer (score 4):

when you configure google connection (for example from within Airflow Web Interface `/Admin/Connections`), set the Number of Retries.

This seem to do it for me, apparently the default is set to `None` which is why it fails.